# call spring action from jquery without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

As you all know that we can call spring action from jquery using ajax. But the problem with that is the return that it gets in ajax needs to be put in div on that page. If I need to open a new page using that action, I mean if the action is calling new page in view, how do we implement it.

In short, I need to know how to call spring mvc action from jquery without ajax.

Comment: `submit form` with html or javascript

Comment: You can again do that by simply submitting the form.And the action which will be called is the action you define in form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to send a get request then you can use window.location.href, which redirect the page to the url you give, for example window.location.href = 'http://yourapp.com/somerequest'; will redirect to somerequest in your application.

If the functionality you want is form submission then you can use $('#formid').submit();